# SQL query sorted by year, counting values per year

Tags: sql-server, date, sum

I have this SQL query, which gives me the numbers of orders within a date range, and that is OK:

```
    SELECT       CardName, ItemNumber, COUNT(*) AS antal, year(date) as aarstal, SUM(Numbers) AS total, sum(case when year(date)=2012 then 1 else 0 end) as newtest
FROM            tblOrders
WHERE        (Publisher = 3) AND (Date > '01-01-2012 00:00:00') AND (Date < '30-09-2014 23:59:59') AND (Status = 3) and ItemNumber!=9130 and ItemNumber!=9180 and ItemNumber!=9170 and ItemNumber!=9190
GROUP BY ItemNumber, CardName, year(date)
```

This gives me ie

```
CompanyA    0   76  2012    10900   76
CompanyA    0   42  2013    6300    0
CompanyB    0   1   2012    100 1
CompanyB    0   7   2013    1100    0
CompanyC    0   1   2014    300 0
CompanyD    0   7   2014    700 0
CompanyE    0   2   2012    300 2
CompanyE    0   1   2013    200 0
```

From this, I can see that CompanyA bought 10900 units in 2012, from a total of 76 orders that year, and in 2013, they bought 6300 units. For sales reasons, we would like (or need) this output as

```
CompanyA    0   76  2012    10900   42  2013    6300
CompanyB    0   1   2012    100 7   2013    1100
CompanyC    0   1   2014    300 0   2013    0
CompanyD    0   7   2014    700 0   2013    0
CompanyE    0   2   2012    300 1   2013    200
```

So you could see if a customer is going up or down in sales. I've tried various things, but I don't know if there is any possibility to have the Numbers column SUM'ed up per year in a query like this, any suggestions?

PS: The

```
sum(case when year(date)=2012 then 1 else 0 end) as newtest
```

was just for a test, I tried something like SUM(Numbers case...) but that was not accepted!

EDIT: I just made a demo in SQL Fiddle, just to give a better understanding of my problem:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/072a1/5

In there, you can see that my customer A has bought a total of 300 in 2012 (on 2 orders), 700 in 2013 (on 2 orders), and finally 200 in 2014 (on 1 order). The pivot examples I've found only counts the number of orders, and not the value of my Numbers - could somebody edit the SQL Fiddle, making that one work, then I'm sure I could learn and adapt the solution into my "real" database?

/Tommy

Comment: Please post the output with column names.

Comment: Column names are not really needed, it's fairly obvious you need to pivot the data. Take a look at [PIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)